# Detect Cracks which is Propagates by time

Tags: python, opencv

I'm writing a code to detect cracks in a plain. By time plain gets more cracks. I need to detect new cracks and save the time when each new crack happens.

I have tried various methods but none of them does what I need. What i.m currently doing is taking x and y coordinates of detected lines and save them in an array in a while loop. so when new frame detected from camera will check whether the old coordinates matches with new coordinates and if not it will be saved as a new crack  line. But this method is not practical because not every time it returns the same cordinates for the lines (im using hough lines)

This is my code

```
while(True):
            retval,frame=cap.read()
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (480,480))
            cv2.imwrite(THIS_FOLDER+"/Specimens/"+specimenName+"/images/"+specimenName+"_"+str(currentCycles)+"_(Baseline).jpg",frame)
            points = np.array([[list(boundPointOne), list(boundPointTwo), list(boundPointThree), list(boundPointFour),list(boundPointFive), list(boundPointSix)]])



            thresh = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Threshold", "Propagation")
            minLength = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Min Line Length", "Propagation")

            if(thresh<0):
                thresh =1


            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


            edges = cv2.Canny(gray, minimumVal, maximumVal, apertureSize = 3)

            minimumVal = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Minimum Value", "Edges")
            maximumVal = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Maximum Value", "Edges")
            croppedFrame=cropROI(frame)
            cropped=cropROI(edges)
            lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=cropped, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=int(thresh), minLineLength=minLength, maxLineGap=25)

            for i in lineList:
                cv2.line(croppedFrame, (i[0],i[1]), (i[2],i[3]), (0,0,255), 1)

            if lines is not None:
                print("Line Detected")
                # Loop through all the coordinates
                for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[0]:

                    print("Coming here")
                    for (x3,y3,x4,y4) in lineList:
                        if not collinear(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
                            if not collinear(x1,y1,x2,y2,x4,y4):
                                 anglea = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
                                 print(anglea)
                                 if not anglea<20 and anglea >50 :

                                     lineList.append((x1, y1, x2, y2))
                                     crackTip = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
                                     print("--------------------------- New Line ---------------------------------------")
                                     break
                            else:


                                 print("-------------------------Linear")
                                 break
                        elif collinear(x1,y1,x2,y2,x4,y4):



                             print("-------------------------Linear")
                             break






                else:
                    crackTip=(0,0,0,0)

                print("Exited")
                requiredLine= cv2.line(croppedFrame, (crackTip[0],crackTip[1]), (crackTip[2],crackTip[3]), (0,255,0), 2)

            cv2.imshow("Edges", edges)
            cv2.imshow("Propagation", croppedFrame)
            for i in range(1, 10):
                cv2.waitKey(1)
```

this is how my image looks like.
Crack Detector with a mask[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gazn.png)

Edges
Detected Edges[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Okhz.png)

Comment: Can you add your original image and expected output image?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to enclose the crack in a bbox and then see if the bbox grows with time. You can find the area of the bbox as well as how the height and length changes with time. This way you can monitor on the widening of the crack as well as growth.

Use the [boundingRect](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) function of OpenCV to find the closed bbox to your points and then keep monitoring the bboxe in each iteration.

Comment: can i put a line into a bounding box using x,y coordinates?

Comment: Yes you can, try using the [boundingRect](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) function of openCV.